# How to detect onchange in a loop with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

This may of already been asked before or there maybe a simple answer to this solution but I am stuck currently. I have this form which can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/DS73u/, where a user can input coordinates in 3 different ways with a unique name. There can also be more than one entrance so the user can add more inputs to the form. I loop through every checkbox input that is checked and store the values into an array 2D array. Where it stores what scheme it is and the coordinate values. So a user inputs 55.67484 and -86.7685 they they get stored into the array and can be accessed by temp[0][0] = 55.67484 AND temp[0][1] = -86.7685.

After that is done, I then want to separate each group of coordinates based on entrance. I store the 2D array into an object property where ent_name is the property name. Although I am having a problem splitting up the values based on entrance name, I don't know how to compare it since all of the values are contained within a loop. Maybe onchange() or change() would work in jquery? The values of the text fields don't ever change per say...

```
$(function() {

    /*
        This is where the magic happens when you click
        the "Preview Map" button
        It does several things...

        1.Loops through every checkbox in the #entrances
        2.Check to see if Entrance name has changed and store it into object with  array of coordinates
        2.Checks to see if the checkbox is checked
            a.Yes
                1.We see what checkbox is being checked
                to determine how we want to output the data
                inputted(Hence the switch)
                2.We grab the data from the form and store it
                into an array called coordinates
            b.No
                1.Do nothing
    */

    $('#prev_map').click(function() {

        //Make sure coordinates is empty before proceeding
        coordinates = {};
        temp = [];
        var ent_name;

        //console.log($('#entrances input:checkbox'));
        $('#entrances input:checkbox').each(function(){

            if (this.checked) {
                    //console.log($(this).parent('#coords').prevAll('input').val());
                    //coordinates.push($(this).parent('#coords').prevAll('input').val());
                    ent_name = $(this).parent('#coords').prevAll('input').map(function() {
                        console.log(ent_name);
                    }).get().change(function() {
                        console.log("We changed");
                    });
                    /*
                    ent_name = $(this).parent('#coords').prevAll('input').map(function() {
                        return $(this).val();
                    }).get();


                    console.log("Entrance Name: " + ent_name);
                    if (temp_name != ent_name) {
                        coordinates[temp_name] = temp;
                    } else {
                        temp = [];
                    };
                    var temp_name = ent_name;
                    console.log("Temporary Name: " + temp_name);*/

                switch(this.name) {

                    case "dec_coord":
                        temp.push($(this,'input').next().children('input').map(function() {
                            return $(this).val();
                        }).get());
                        break;
                    case "deg_coord":
                        var temp2 = $(this,'input').next().children("input,select").map(function() {
                            return $(this).val();
                        }).get().join(";");
                        //console.log(temp);
                        temp2 = temp2.toString();
                        temp2 = temp2.replace(";","°");
                        temp2 = temp2.replace(";","'");
                        temp2 = temp2.replace(";","\"");
                        temp2 = temp2.replace(";",",");
                        temp2 = temp2.replace(";","°");
                        temp2 = temp2.replace(";","'");
                        temp2 = temp2.replace(";","\"");
                        temp.push(temp2.split(","));
                        break;
                    case "utm_coord":
                        temp.push($(this,'input').next().children('input,select').map(function() {
                            return $(this).val();
                        }).get().join(","));
                        break;
                }

            } else {
                //console.log("wrong");
            };



        });

        $('#dialog').dialog({
            width: 500,
            height: 400,
            open: function() {
                //loadMap();
            }
        });
    });
    /*
            This is the replication of the Entrance Fields
            We will limit the number of entrances to 5
        */

        var template = $('#entrances .ent_clone:first').clone();
            var cloneCount = 0;

            var addEntrance = function(){
                cloneCount++;
                var entrance = template.clone().find(':input').each(function() {
                    var newID = this.id+cloneCount;
                    //$(this).prev().attr('for', newID);
                    this.id = newID;
                }).end()
                .attr('id', 'ent' + cloneCount)
                .appendTo("#ent");
            };
            $('#addEnt').click(addEntrance);
});
```

Comment: If you solved your problem, you can post an answer to your own question and then accept the answer. This will officially "close" the question and help others in the future so they know that there is a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do was add each ent_name into an array and the looping value to compare them. . So I did this:

```
   ent_name.push($(this).parent('#coords').prevAll('input').val());
   var testent = $(this).parent('#coords').prevAll('input').val();
```

After that I created an if statement, comparing the 1st value of the array to the most recent value in the loop.

```
   if (ent_name[i].toString() != testent)
```

After that I made the ent_name the object property and added the array to that specific property with the values.

```
   coordinates[ent_name[i]] = temp;
```

Then I cleared the temp array that was storing the recent coordinates.

```
   temp = [];
```

Finally, I incremented my comparison variable to the latest ent_name by doing this:

```
   i = ent_name.length;
```

You will need to add the 
coordinates[ent_name[i]] = temp; after the last loop so you can store the last elements into the object as well.

So the ending code was this:

```
        ent_name.push($(this).parent('#coords').prevAll('input').val());
    var testent = $(this).parent('#coords').prevAll('input').val();
                    //console.log(ent_name[i++]);
                    //console.log(ent_name);

                    //console.log(temp);
                    if (ent_name[i].toString() != testent) {
                        //console.log(temp);
                        console.log(ent_name);
                        coordinates[ent_name[i]] = temp;
                        temp = [];
                        i = ent_name.length;
                    }
```

Simple and stupid of me for wasting so many hours but I learned a lot.

Cheers!
Ratty

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following everything here, but it sounds like you're question is about how to best store your information, where you have an array of lat/lon data for each entrance.

If ent_name is indeed a unique key which you do not expect to change, perhaps a javascript object:

```
var myEntrances = {};
...
myEntrances[ent_name] = temp;
```

Comment: Well I have that, but this is the issue. What I am trying to do is this. I grab the entrance's name from the input on the cloned form and store the array of coordinates into that property name. The issue is that it is storing all values from the array into the entrance property.

Comment: So my first thought was to compare ent_name with the previous name to see if they were different, but the value is being changed each time within the loop so it wasn't possible. I believe I am just missing some simple logic here.

Comment: One simple thing I noticed... you should probably be appending your cloned div to `#entrances` rather than `#ent`

Comment: Also, since you're making a unique id for the containing div, I'd recommend using that as your key for your data storage rather than the name that somebody enters for the entrance in an input box.  It's guaranteed to be unique, while the human data is not.

Comment: I can't append them to #entrances because each time I do a clone it doubles the amount of boxes since #ent is being cloned. I did solve my problem after way too many hours. I will post it above. Thank you though for the assistance, I truly do appreciate it.